# relocation error while linking an object file using alink which is of win32 format created using nasm assembler

Tags: assembly, nasm, relocation

I am using nasm to assemble my `xyz.asm` file to `xyz.obj` using command :

```
nasm -f win32 xyz.asm
```

Linking it using `alink` gives the relocation error.

Please help me to fix this problem.

Comment: `Alink` is rather an older linker, although it "should" still work. Jeremy Gordon's `Golink` is more popular these days. If you want to use `Alink`, can you provide more information about the file that exhibits this error?

Comment: The code is here http://imgur.com/lnhHKYu

Comment: You'd want `alink -oPE gcdi.obj` at least, I think. You still need an entrypoint.

Comment: how to specify an entry point??

Comment: You could try `alink -oPE -entry xyz gcdi.obj`. What you've got there is a subroutine which expects two parameters on the stack and calculates the gcd of them. You'd need a separate ("main"?) caller or a "testmain" as part of the file to make a "sensible"  executable out of it. The above command line might shut Alink up, but it won't do anything useful.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.Can you please tell me a sample code for gcd,that takes two numbers and tell their gcd?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I can't give you "tested" code to call your gcd sample in Windows (won't do Windows). It might look a little like this, but this is probably not close enough to actually work.

```
; nasm -f win32 callgcd.asm
; alink -oPE -entry _main callgcd.obj gcdi.obj win32.lib

global _main
extern _scanf
extern _printf
extern ExitProcess
extern xyz ; that's what you called it

section .data
    fmt db "%i", 0

section .bss
    number1 resd 1
    number2 resd 1

section .text
     _main:

    push number1
    push fmt
    call _scanf
    add esp 4 * 2

    push number2
    push fmt
    call _scanf
    add esp, 4 * 2

    push dword [number1]
    push dword [number2]
    call xyz
    add esp, 4 * 2

    push eax
    push fmt
    call _printf
    add esp, 4 * 2

    push 0
    call ExitProcess
```

Perhaps some Windows user can give you something better.

Answer (score -2):

tell nasm you want .obj file first. alink should work fine after that

```
nasm -f win32 xyz.asm -o xyz.o or -o xyz.obj
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Um.. NASM creates an object file named xyz.obj by default: _"The `win32` output format generates Microsoft Win32 object files ... `win32` provides a default output file-name extension of `.obj`."_